# Set chrome to offline mode using protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having problems finding out, how to set browser to offline mode on test runtime. I tried `browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand` but it doesn't work.

```
  async toggleOfflineMode(action: 'enable' | 'disable') {
    action === 'enable'
      ? await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Network.emulateNetworkConditions', {
        offline: true,
        latency: 0,
        downloadThroughput: 0,
        uploadThroughput: 0,
        connectionType: 'none'
      })
      : await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Network.emulateNetworkConditions', {
        offline: false,
        latency: 0,
        downloadThroughput: -1,
        uploadThroughput: -1,
        connectionType: 'ethernet'
      });
  }
```

Comment: I've used "protocol monitor" in devtools and it shows an additional property: `connectionType: "none"`

Comment: Sadly, it didn't help

Comment: Maybe you need to send `Network.enable` first.

Comment: I found complete solution here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/11/12/testing-application-in-offline-network-mode/#going-online

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made something like this:

```
async toggleBrowserOfflineMode(mode: 'online' | 'offline') {
  mode === 'offline' ?
    await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Network.enable', {}).then(async () => {
      await this.setNetworkConditions(true);
    }) :
    await this.setNetworkConditions(false).then(async () => {
      await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Network.disable', {});
    });
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(mode === 'online');
}

async setNetworkConditions(isOffline: boolean) {
  await browser.driver.sendChromiumCommand('Network.emulateNetworkConditions', {
    offline: isOffline,
    latency: -1,
    downloadThroughput: -1,
    uploadThroughput: -1,
  });
}
```